# How can I monitor "primary and secondary" Cognos nodes?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, cognos

We have several Content Managers in Cognos that are running: one as a primary, one as a secondary.

I would like to be alerted if there isn't one node acting as primary, if the primary node changed, or if the uptime changed.

This information is available via this webpage: http://cognosServer.com:9300/p2pd/servlet

Is there a more useful script or tool I can use to extract the status for Nagios, or any other tool?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use JMX to check on the app itself. [There are a lot of resources for JMX monitoring in Nagios Exchange](http://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=jmx), but I couldn't recommend a specific plugin.

At a higher level, you might want to use [check_multi](http://my-plugin.de/wiki/projects/check_multi/start) to check them as a service cluster.

Neither of these will get you a Cognos-specific "is this the master?" functionality, though. You'd probably have to write something to parse the p2pd servlet page to achieve that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two servers hosted in public network?. If so, there are few online URL monitoring sites are available to keep monitoring of the server availability round the clock and alert via an email when the server in not responding state. This works only when the server hosted in public network. And the configuration of Primary and Secondary server URL must be differentiated in the URL monitoring sites in order to know which server has got status change.

Hope this helps.